# I am trying to fetch data from the api and display it in a DropDownButton. problem is that snapshot is returning null

Tags: json, api, flutter, jsondecoder, dropdownbutton

snapshot.hasData is returning null and the drop button never gets displayed.

I am trying to fetch data from the api and display it in a dropdown button. 
the response.body is fetched correctly as it gets printed when i try to print it. 
But when I try to print listOfOperators, nothing is printed. 
Looks like the listOfOperators is empty, hence the snapshot doesnt have any data. 
I am not able to figure out why this is the case

JsonData:

{"status": "success", "OperatorType": "GAS", "data": {"MAHANAGAR_GAS_LTD": {"name": "Mahanagar Gas Limited", "authenticator3": null, "label": "Customer Account Number (12 digits start with 21)", "note": null, "account_label": "Bill Group Number (1 - 8 characters + digits)", "authenticator3_options": null}, "TRIPURA_NATURAL_GAS_COMPANY_LTD": {"name": "Tripura Natural Gas Company Ltd", "authenticator3": null, "label": "Consumer Number (1 - 20 digits)", "note": null, "account_label": null, "authenticator3_options": null}, "HARAYANA_CITY_GAS": {"name": "Haryana City gas", "authenticator3": null, "label": "CRN Number (8-12 digits)", "note": null, "account_label": null, "authenticator3_options": null}, "GUJARAT_GAS_COMPANY_LTD": {"name": "Gujarat Gas company Limited", "authenticator3": null, "label": "Service Number (1-15 digits)", "note": null, "account_label": null, "authenticator3_options": null}, "VADODARA_GAS_LTD": {"name": "Aavantika Gas Ltd", "authenticator3": null, "label": "Customer Number (10-15 Alphanumeric)", "note": null, "account_label": null, "authenticator3_options": null}, "SGL": {"name": "Sabarmati Gas Limited (SGL)", "authenticator3": null, "label": "Customer ID (12 digits)", "note": null, "account_label": null, "authenticator3_options": null}, "SITI_ENERGY": {"name": "Siti Energy", "authenticator3": null, "label": "ARN Number (7 - 9 digits)", "note": null, "account_label": null, "authenticator3_options": null}, "UCPGPL": {"name": "Unique Central Piped Gases Pvt Ltd (UCPGPL)", "authenticator3": null, "label": "Customer Number (8 digits + character)", "note": null, "account_label": null, "authenticator3_options": null}, "IGL": {"name": "IGL (Indraprasth Gas Limited)", "authenticator3": null, "label": "Consumer Number (10 digits)", "note": null, "account_label": null, "authenticator3_options": null}, "ADANI_GAS": {"name": "ADANI GAS", "authenticator3": null, "label": "Customer ID (10 digits)", "note": null, "account_label": null, "authenticator3_options": null}}}

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class JsonApiDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  JsonApiDropdownState createState() {
    return new JsonApiDropdownState();
  }
}

class JsonApiDropdownState extends State<JsonApiDropdown> {
  Operators _currentOperator;
  final String uri = "https://stage.linq.store/recharge-bill-payments?load=GetOperators&type=GAS";

  Future<List<Operators>> _fetchdata() async {
    var response = await http.get(uri, 
      headers: {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "MyToken" : "Token d5c9912f-4d4a-4776-88c4-545779804040",
        "Request-Type" : "mobile_api",
      }
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final operators = jsonDecode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      List<Operators> listOfOperators = operators.map<Operators>((json) {
        return Operators.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();

      return listOfOperators;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load internet');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Gas Bill Payment'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<List<Operators>>(
                future: _fetchdata(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<Operators>> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      return DropdownButton<Operators>(
                        items: snapshot.data
                            .map((operator) => DropdownMenuItem<Operators>(
                                  child: Text(operator.name),
                                  value: operator,
                                ))
                            .toList(),
                        onChanged: (Operators value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentOperator = value;
                          });
                        },
                        isExpanded: false,
                        value: _currentOperator,
                        hint: Text('Select Operator'),
                        );
                }),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                _currentOperator != null
                    ? Text("Name: " +
                        _currentOperator.name +
                        "\n Label: " +
                        _currentOperator.label +
                        "\n Account Label: " +
                        _currentOperator.accountLabel)
                    : Text("No Operator selected"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Operators {
  String name;
  String label;
  String accountLabel;

  Operators({
    this.name,
    this.label,
    this.accountLabel
  });

  factory Operators.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Operators(
      name: json['name'],
      label: json['label'],
      accountLabel: json['account_label'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you get through the `== 200` test?

Comment: Yes, because if it didnt get through, an exception would have been thrown which wasnt the case. Somehow, listOfOperators is blank. Either a problem with json.decode or maping. @RichardHeap

Comment: When I comment out the line if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator(); then an exception is thrown which reads NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'map'

Comment: Whenever I use builder, I always check  the case where snapshot == null || snapshot.data == null. After that I use the data. I have never met any issues.

Comment: @HoànLê i tried using that as well. the point is that snapshot is null and hence i cannot build the dropdown. any suggestions why it could be null.

Comment: Hi! When you parse the json response `return Operators.fromJson(json);`. Are you sure json has any value? Does the console prints any error?

Comment: @Sebastian As per the json data returned from the response, i think json.decode(response.body)['data'] will be the correct way. i will include the json data in the body. Please have a look and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Created my own example based on you json, and loaded your json locally ,else everything is the same.
check out the code below i have provided the json, model class  and the main dart file.

Your json file below:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "OperatorType": "GAS",
    "data": {
        "MAHANAGAR_GAS_LTD": {
            "name": "Mahanagar Gas Limited",
            "authenticator3": null,
            "label": "Customer Account Number (12 digits start with 21)",
            "note": null,
            "account_label": "Bill Group Number (1 - 8 characters + digits)",
            "authenticator3_options": null
        },
        "TRIPURA_NATURAL_GAS_COMPANY_LTD": {
            "name": "Tripura Natural Gas Company Ltd",
            "authenticator3": null,
            "label": "Consumer Number (1 - 20 digits)",
            "note": null,
            "account_label": null,
            "authenticator3_options": null
        },
        "HARAYANA_CITY_GAS": {
            "name": "Haryana City gas",
            "authenticator3": null,
            "label": "CRN Number (8-12 digits)",
            "note": null,
            "account_label": null,
            "authenticator3_options": null
        },
        "GUJARAT_GAS_COMPANY_LTD": {
            "name": "Gujarat Gas company Limited",
            "authenticator3": null,
            "label": "Service Number (1-15 digits)",
            "note": null,
            "account_label": null,
            "authenticator3_options": null
        },
        "VADODARA_GAS_LTD": {
            "name": "Aavantika Gas Ltd",
            "authenticator3": null,
            "label": "Customer Number (10-15 Alphanumeric)",
            "note": null,
            "account_label": null,
            "authenticator3_options": null
        },
        "SGL": {
            "name": "Sabarmati Gas Limited (SGL)",
            "authenticator3": null,
            "label": "Customer ID (12 digits)",
            "note": null,
            "account_label": null,
            "authenticator3_options": null
        },
        "SITI_ENERGY": {
            "name": "Siti Energy",
            "authenticator3": null,
            "label": "ARN Number (7 - 9 digits)",
            "note": null,
            "account_label": null,
            "authenticator3_options": null
        },
        "UCPGPL": {
            "name": "Unique Central Piped Gases Pvt Ltd (UCPGPL)",
            "authenticator3": null,
            "label": "Customer Number (8 digits + character)",
            "note": null,
            "account_label": null,
            "authenticator3_options": null
        },
        "IGL": {
            "name": "IGL (Indraprasth Gas Limited)",
            "authenticator3": null,
            "label": "Consumer Number (10 digits)",
            "note": null,
            "account_label": null,
            "authenticator3_options": null
        },
        "ADANI_GAS": {
            "name": "ADANI GAS",
            "authenticator3": null,
            "label": "Customer ID (10 digits)",
            "note": null,
            "account_label": null,
            "authenticator3_options": null
        }
    }
}
```

Model class defined for the json you provided :

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final operators = operatorsFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Operators operatorsFromJson(String str) => Operators.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String operatorsToJson(Operators data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Operators {
  String status;
  String operatorType;
  Map<String, Datum> data;

  Operators({
    this.status,
    this.operatorType,
    this.data,
  });

  factory Operators.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Operators(
        status: json["status"],
        operatorType: json["OperatorType"],
        data: Map.from(json["data"])
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Datum>(k, Datum.fromJson(v))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "OperatorType": operatorType,
        "data": Map.from(data)
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      };
}

class Datum {
  String name;
  dynamic authenticator3;
  String label;
  dynamic note;
  String accountLabel;
  dynamic authenticator3Options;

  Datum({
    this.name,
    this.authenticator3,
    this.label,
    this.note,
    this.accountLabel,
    this.authenticator3Options,
  });

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        name: json["name"],
        authenticator3: json["authenticator3"],
        label: json["label"],
        note: json["note"],
        accountLabel:
            json["account_label"] == null ? null : json["account_label"],
        authenticator3Options: json["authenticator3_options"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "authenticator3": authenticator3,
        "label": label,
        "note": note,
        "account_label": accountLabel == null ? null : accountLabel,
        "authenticator3_options": authenticator3Options,
      };
}
```

And this is the main file that i have written for the dropdown with your data

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sample_testing_project/models.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Datum> data = List();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  String selectedOperator;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadYourData();
  }

  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  loadYourData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    // Loading your json locally you can make an api call, when you get the response just pass it to the operatorsFromJson method
    String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();
    final operators = operatorsFromJson(jsonString);

    operators.data.forEach((k, v) {
      data.add(v);
    });

    print(data.length);
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _isLoading
            ? Text('Loading')
            : Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          width: 0.80),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButton(
                        value: selectedOperator,
                        isExpanded: true,
                        icon: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                        ),
                        iconSize: 25,
                        underline: SizedBox(),
                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedOperator = newValue;
                          });
                        },
                        hint: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text('Select'),
                        ),
                        items: data.map((data) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: data.name,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                              child: Text(
                                data.name,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList()),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have loaded your json locally from the loadFromAssets method but you can call your api and then pass the response.body to operatorsFromJson method.

Else every thing is the same, i have just removed every value (thats object) from the key,value map and the addded in the list and displayed it in the dropdown.
Let me know if it works.